# Updating a pictureBox.Image from another class

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox, mvp

**Update:** I am pretty sure i found out the reason why, i will update this question with my findings as soon as i got it for sure. It is related to having 2 usercontrol's placed above each other and i draw on the one behind thats why i don't see the changes! I had to check the hashcode of the timer to figure out that 2 timers are involved.

---

I am developing a winforms application and i have applied the MVP-pattern to separate the responsibilities and stuff... (applied the passive-view approach, and also fire events to require the corresponding presenter to perform an action).

I have also checked other questions here and many other relevant topics, but nothing helped...

**Problem description:** I added a `UserControl` (`SubView`) into a `SplitContainer`'s `panel` which is placed inside a `Form` (`MainView`). This `SubView` has its own presenter (`SubPresenter`) that requires it to switch its background (`SwitchBackground()`, `picturebox`) whenever that is triggered by the user from the `MainView`.

**Problem:** The `SwitchBackground()` method gets executed (i debugged that) when that is triggered from the `MainView` (actually from the `MainPresenter`), but **the changes are not displayed** on the `SubView`. I have also examined (or at least tried to do that correctly :) ) if the method requires switching the context into the GUI thread or something by checking the `InvokeRequired`.

I would be glad to have any recommendations regarding this issue, because i am stuck there and can't go further with programming...

Here is an example application i wrote to illustrate the problem (for the complete example project, i uploaded it on github: [link](https://github.com/developer-ly/mvp_demo)):

**SubView:**

```
public interface ISubView
{
    void StartSwitchingBackground();
    void StopSwitchingBackground();
}

public partial class SubView : UserControl, ISubView
{
    private Bitmap plot;
    private Brush brush1;
    private Brush brush2;
    private int drawCount;

    private Timer timer;

    public SubView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        brush1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        brush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += OnTick;
    }

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SwitchBackground();
    }

    private void SwitchBackground()
    {

        if (InvokeRequired)
            Console.WriteLine("InvokeRequired");    // never happens, so i assume it is not considered a call from another thread...

        if (plot == null || plot.Size != pictureBox.Size)
            plot = new Bitmap((int)(pictureBox.Width*0.8), (int)(pictureBox.Height*0.8));

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(plot))
        {
            int x = plot.Width / 2;
            int y = plot.Height / 2;
            int w = plot.Width / 4;
            int h = plot.Height / 4;

            if (drawCount % 2 == 0)
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.FillRectangle(brush1, (x - w) / 2, (y - h) / 2, w, h);
            }
            else
            {
                g.Clear(Color.Black);
                g.FillRectangle(brush2, (x - w) / 2, (y - h) / 2, w, h);
            }
            drawCount++;
        }
        pictureBox.Image = plot;
    }

    public void StartSwitchingBackground()
    {
        if (!timer.Enabled)
            timer.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("started");
    }

    public void StopSwitchingBackground()
    {
        if (timer.Enabled) timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("stopped");
    }

    private void btnStartSwitching_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartSwitchingBackground();
    }

    private void btnStopSwitching_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopSwitchingBackground();
    }
}
```

**SubPresenter:**

```
public class SubPresenter
{
    private ISubView view;

    public SubPresenter(ISubView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void SwitchBackground()
    {
        view.StartSwitchingBackground();
    }

    public void StopSwitching()
    {
        view.StopSwitchingBackground();
    }
}
```

**MainView:**

```
public interface IMainView
{
    ISubView SubView { get; }
    event EventHandler SwitchEventTriggered;
    event EventHandler StopSwitchEventTriggered;
}

public partial class MainView : Form, IMainView
{
    private SubView subView;
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        subView = new SubView();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(subView);
        subView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        subView.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top & AnchorStyles.Left;
        splitContainer1.Resize += splitContainer1_Resize;
    }

    void splitContainer1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        subView.Size = splitContainer1.Panel2.Size;
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartSwitching();
    }

    private void StartSwitching()
    {
        OnStartSwitchingTriggered();
    }

    private void OnStartSwitchingTriggered()
    {
        var handler = SwitchEventTriggered;
        if (handler == null) return;
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopSwitching();
    }

    private void StopSwitching()
    {
        OnStopSwitching();
    }

    private void OnStopSwitching()
    {
        var handler = StopSwitchEventTriggered;
        if (handler == null) return;
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public ISubView SubView { get { return this.subView; } }
    public event EventHandler SwitchEventTriggered;
    public event EventHandler StopSwitchEventTriggered;
}
```

**MainPresenter:**

public class MainPresenter
    {
        private readonly IMainView mainView;

```
    private readonly SubPresenter subPresenter;

    public MainPresenter(IMainView view)
    {
        this.mainView = view;
        this.subPresenter = new SubPresenter(mainView.SubView);
        mainView.SwitchEventTriggered += OnSwitchEventTriggerd;
        mainView.StopSwitchEventTriggered += OnStopSwitchEventTriggered;
    }

    private void OnStopSwitchEventTriggered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        subPresenter.StopSwitching();
    }

    private void OnSwitchEventTriggerd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        subPresenter.SwitchBackground();
    }
}
```

**Entry Point:**

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MainView mainView = new MainView();
        MainPresenter mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(mainView);

        Application.Run(mainView);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that the right picture box is changing the background (white->black), what exactly is not working?

Comment: this happens only if you trigger that from inside the usercontrol (subview). the "start" and "stop" buttons on the MainView (found near the bottom left corner of the view) should cause the same effect, but that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two instances of SubView in MainView.
Use only subView1, you can delete all occurrences of subView;

The minimum fix is to replace:

```
public ISubView SubView { get { return this.subView; } }
```

with:

```
public ISubView SubView { get { return this.subView1; } }
```

Comment: yep, thats what i realized this morning and could fix the problem. i am soon done with the application :) thanks a lot for your time.